# Неккоректное отрабатывание if(isset($var) and isset($var2))

Tags: php

Делаю поиск по дате
есть форма

```
<form action="" id="sDateEnd" method="post">
        <input type="date" name="search-start-date">
        <input type="date" name="search-end-date">
        <button type="submit" id="subDateStart" name="searchDateStart">
        <span>Пошук</span>
        </button>
        <button type="button" id="clearDateStart" name="clearDateStart">
        <span>Відміна</span>
        </button>
        </form>
```

при тыке на поиск аяксом летят на сервер значения POST и происходит следующее:
Проблема 1. - я никак не попадаю сюда. При сабмите формы я всегда попадаю в `else`.

```
if ((isset($_POST['search-start-date']) === false) and (isset($_POST['search-end-date']) === false)):
//проверяю есть ли тут что либо вообще, если нет - выходим.
    return false;
else:
```

Далее то что находится в `else`:
Проблема 2. - При поиске какого-то одного значения - у меня отрабатывает нужное мне условие но также почему-то всегда отрабатывает условие для поиска интервала.

```
if ((isset($_POST['search-start-date']) === true) and (isset($_POST['search-end-date']) === true)):
        echo "interval";
//Проверяю вдруг у нас ищется интервал дат от и до.
        $tasks = getSearchIntervalDate($_POST['search-start-date'], $_POST['search-end-date']);
    endif;
```

То что дальше в else:

```
if (isset($_POST['search-end-date']) === false):
        if (isset($_POST['search-start-date']) === true):
            echo "posle";
            $tasks = getSearchAfterDate($_POST['search-start-date']);
        endif;
    endif;
```

Весь код полностью:

```
if (($_POST['search-start-date'] == "") and ($_POST['search-end-date']) == ""):
    return false;
else:
    if ((isset($_POST['search-start-date']) !== "" and (isset($_POST['search-end-date']) !== ""))):
        echo "interval";
        $tasks = getSearchIntervalDate($_POST['search-start-date'], $_POST['search-end-date']);
    endif;
    if ($_POST['search-start-date'] == ""):
        if ($_POST['search-end-date'] !== ""):
            echo "do";
        $tasks = getSearchBeforeDate($_POST['search-end-date']);
        endif;
    endif;
    if ($_POST['search-end-date'] == ""):
        if ($_POST['search-start-date'] !== ""):
            echo "posle";
            $tasks = getSearchAfterDate($_POST['search-start-date']);
        endif;
    endif;
    renderTaskList($tasks);
endif;
```

Очевидно ошибка в логике условий, но никак не могу вкурить где именно.

Comment: первым делом исправьте все isset($_POST['...']) === false на isset($_POST['...']), далее прочитайте тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php и тут: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php

Comment: заменил, теперь отрабатывают все условия :\

Comment: в isset можно передать сразу несколько переменных. будет `true`, только если ВСЕ установлены, если что-то не установлено - `false`. Ну нужен огород с `and`

Comment: Да я знаю, что в isset можно передать несколько переменных, но тут проблема в том что у меня есть условие когда инпут 1 и инпут 2 = тру, и условие когда только 1 инпут тру. Они срабатывают одновременно, а не должны.

Comment: @Антон обратитесь к мануалам по ссылкам из коммента выше. Вы используете проверку тождественного равентсва (===), которое вам и провоцирует неожидаемое поведение скрипта.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/types.comparisons.php - Если и это не поможет, то тут наши полномочия всё

Comment: грызу мануальчик, разбираюсь

Answer (score 1):

`isset` и `с одним заполненнным инпутом` - вещи не пересекающиеся. `isset` проверяет, что переменная (или в частности элемент массива) существует и не `NULL`. Незаполненный элемент формы `input type="date"` всё равно отправляется в теле запроса в виде пустой строки. Пустая строка прилетающая с формы - это не отсутствие элемента и не `NULL`, это пустая строка.

Comment: Я делал с пустыми строками, но тоже не получалось, сейчас покажу что было.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.